# Can A Person Move Out Before 60 Days

Tags: contract-law, tenant

I dont understand why it HAS to be 60 days notice that a tenant must give.  Why can you not give notice to your landlord and just move out say within a month?  What happens if your living in a unit where the building is so unkept as far as maintenance goes etc?  Where I live the maintenance is so poorly kept the Fire Marshall has already been after the landlord.  The place has mold all over the bathroom,  Its a shared accomodation type dwelling.  Shared kitchen, shared bathroom.  The place is infested with roaches which the landlord doesnt spray no matter how much you ask. and when he does he gets crabby about it. Theres bed bugs in here.  So far we've had to buy our own spray which doesnt obviously get all the roaches. Very little heat in here.  I dont know what to do.  Tenant act says 60 days but I cant live here much longer.

Comment: You don't have to stay there during the 60 days: you just have to pay for them.

Answer (score 2):

That is either what the lease says, or what state law says, or both. In like manner, the law or the contract might protect your interest in staying there (if you wanted to), by requiring the landlord to give you some amount of advance notice. 30 and 60 days are "natural" periods -- nobody ever writes this stuff for 37 days. It is remotely possible that you have a more immediate remedy, if the place is truly uninhabitable, so you might speak with the Fire Marshall, in case the place is a danger to life and limb. Your local landlord-tenant act will spell out standards of habitability: presence of roaches is not ever, as far as I know, a breach of the landlord's warrant of habitability.